# powerpoint 2013 vba resize text in slide mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a textbox on my powerpoint 2013 slide that gets populated with text whilst the slideshow is running.

This is achieved with some vba code that gets data from a database.

If the text gets too long I need to resize it to fit inside the textbox.

All of the auto resize examples I have tried do not seem to affect the slide whilst it is running.

I can write a function that reduces the font size until it fits but I don't seem to be able to get the actual height the text is taking up!

Please help!!!

Comment: The textrange's .BoundHeight property will give you the height the text takes up.